# Cordova command not running through cron job

Tags: python, cordova, cron

I am trying to make one cron job script in Python . For the start what i did i just add the code to run the cordova and show its version the same python file works if i run it through shell but when its run through cron job it gives me this error

```
    env: node: No such file or directory
```

Python file has this code

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   import os
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call('/usr/local/bin/cordova -v',shell=True)
```

Is there any solution for that ? What i get to understand that maybe when i run code through cronjob the global variables are not accessable . Is there anyway that i can get access to command line terminal through pipe and get access to all the global variables ?

Comment: Cron jobs typically [run as root](https://serverfault.com/questions/247043/what-user-do-scripts-in-the-cron-folders-run-as-i-e-cron-daily-cron-hourly). [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/352835/crontab-running-as-a-specific-user) has some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `env` command from your terminal and cronjob script (e.g.: `env > cron_output file`), it will give the environment variables available for normal terminal and cronjob. Compare that variables and export the required missing variables in your script.